# What is the best practice for using Unity Mvc and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container, dbcontext

- What is the best practice to instantiate my DbContext?

I see some people creating an empty interface for the DbContext like this:

```
public interface IEasyDayContext : IDisposable { }
```

and then register it in Unity like this (UnityConfig.cs):

```
container.RegisterType<IEasyDayContext, EasyDayContext>();
```

I see others using the DbContext as an "interface":

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, EasyDayContext>();
```

I see other people just instantiating the DbContext in the constructor of the service.

- I am finding it hard to get updated documentation on Unity Mvc, should I even use it today?
- How do I setup Unity Mvc?

Current documentation (from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Dependency-Injection-in-11d54863) suggests that I should put this line of code in my Global.asax.cs file:

```
UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
```

However, this method doesn't exist anymore. Should I use this instead?

```
UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(UnityConfig.Container);
```

- Should I use PerRequestLifetimeManager?

I am using

```
AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6
Unity.Mvc 5.0.15
Unity.Container 5.8.10
```

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Look for *"Step 4- Register the Dependency in UnityConfig.cs file"* in your linked documentation. If you follow it closely, a `RegisterComponents` method will exist.

Comment: Regarding your other question: setting up unity mvc and registering EF contexts within any dependency resolver framework are very different things. That's why I vote to close as to broad.

Comment: @mbharanidharan88 AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6, Unity.Mvc 5.0.15

Comment: This isn't about Unity. It's about dependency injection in general. When you register *any* type of service through an interface it's easy to test your code using a mock service or dummy object that only needs to implement that interface. Of course, that means that `IEasyDayContext` should *not* be empty.

Comment: The link does *not* point to Unity, only to a 3 year old example. You'll find [Unity Container](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) on Github. Unity itself is [availabler through NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Container) and the current version is 5.8.11

Comment: @grek40 UnityConfig and the RegisterComponents() method is created by Unity. Today, when installing unity, the only method in the class is RegisterTypes().

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I am aware. I have 5.8.10 installed via NuGet. The documentation on GitHub doesn't really help me with trying to understand how to use it properly.

Comment: @AsgerVestbjerg what did you try? A 3 year old *sample* about a completely unrelated version won't help you - Unity.Container was completely rearchitected.

Comment: @AsgerVestbjerg the use of interfaces is the same for *every* DI container though. Interfaces are used so consumers don't depend on a specific implementation of that interface, making testing easier. An *empty* interface doesn't help in that. Registering as `DbContext` is meaningless and most likely a sign of a bug - whoever did that would have to *cast* the injected `DbContext` parameter to an actual parameter

Comment: @AsgerVestbjerg did you check the [Examples](https://github.com/unitycontainer/examples) repository?